# Нарушение прав доступа при чтении по адресу 0x0000000000000000

Tags: c, функции, указатели

Вот такая программа (в задании нужно сделать всё через функции).

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#define _CRT_NONSTDC_NO_WARNINGS
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<locale.h>
#include<math.h>

void vvod(int A[10], int i) {
    srand(time(NULL));
    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        *(A + i) = rand();

    }
}

void vivod(int i, int A[10]) {
    printf("Массив из 10 чисел:\n");
    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        printf("%d) %d\n", i + 1, *(A + i));
    }
    
}
void raschot1(int i, int A[10]) {
    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        if (*(A + i) % 10 == 0)
            printf("Число оканчивающиеся на 0 под номером: %d \n", i + 1);
    }
}
void vvod2(int B[6][5], int b, int d) {
    for (d = 0; d < 6; d++) {
        for (b = 0; b < 5; b++) {
            *(*(B + d) + b) = rand() % 10;
        }
    }
}
void vivod2(int B[6][5], int b, int d) {
    printf("\nБаллы, которые набрали спортсмены в каждом виде спорта:\n");
    for (d = 0; d < 6; d++) {
        for (b = 0; b < 5; b++) {
            printf("%d\t", *(*(B + d) + b));
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
void raschot2(int B[6][5], int i, int j, int sum[6], int min, int max, int* mi, int* ma) {
    for (i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
            *(sum + i) += *(*(B + i) + j);
        }
        if (*(sum + i) > *ma) *ma = *(sum + i);
        if (*(sum + i) < *mi) *mi = *(sum + i);
    }
    printf("Количество баллов набранное спортсменом занявшим последнее место: %d\n", *mi);
    printf("Количество баллов набранное спортсменом победителем: %d\n", *ma);
}
void main() {
    setlocale(LC_ALL, ".1251");
    int A[10], i = 0;
    int B[6][5], b = 0, d = 0;
    int j = 0, sum[6] = { 1 }, min = 100000, max = 0;
    int* mi = &min;
    int* ma = &max;
    vvod(A, i);
    vivod(i, A);
    raschot1(i, A);
    vvod2(B, b, d);
    vivod2(B, b, d);
    raschot2(i, sum, min, max, mi, ma, j, B);
    getch();
}
```

И на этой строчке `*(sum + i) += *(*(B + i) + j);`.  Выдаёт вот такое:

Необработанное исключение по адресу 0x00007FF7341C1D34 в ConsoleApplication1.exe: 0xC0000005: нарушение прав доступа при чтении по адресу 0x0000000000000000.

Хотя если делать всё просто в одной функции main, то всё работает.

Comment: *(sum + i) += *(*(B + i) + j); - не верно sum[ i] += B[ i][ j];

Comment: Нужно именно с помощью указателей

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Конечно, С такое непотребство скомпилирует:

```
void raschot2(int B[6][5], int i, int j, int sum[6], int min, int max, int* mi, int* ma) {
...
int j = 0, sum[6] = { 1 }, min = 100000, max = 0;
...
raschot2(i, sum, min, max, mi, ma, j, B);
```

Но вы же вместо массива передаете целое число! Понятно, что при выполнении получается полная ерунда — вы обращаетесь по адресу 0 (значение переменной `i`) и получаете неприятности.

Передавайте в функции правильные аргументы!

Comment: Ахаххахах. Сижу голову ломаю с автором xD

Comment: Я если честно не особо понял о чём вы)

Comment: Тогда все очень плохо, и это не ваш код... Вы говорите функции, что передадите ей массив, а передаете какое-то число. Что должна делать функция? Ну, например, представьте себе, что вы вызываете функцию `sqrt("Two")` — что вы получите? Или `x = 5 * "три"`... Теперь понятнее?

Comment: Нет, не особо понятнее) Код мой, я могу скинуть как я его делал без функции и даже без указателей. Но я всё равно не понимаю, где я вместо массива передаю переменную. Везде стоят названия массивов, у меня мозг плавиться.

Comment: Что такое `i` в `raschot2(i,...`? Массив? Ну посмотрите же: что *должно* передаваться первым аргументом в `raschot2`? Массив: `int B[6][5]`. А вы что передаете?

Comment: Спасибо, я не знал, что важен порядок. Но теперь вместо минимальной суммы выдаёт вот такое:-858993448, а вместо максимальной - ноль. Не знаете, что с этим делать?

Comment: Ну и как тогда, по-вашему, компилятор может определить, что ему передано? Например, есть функция от двух целых чисел, скажем, поделить одно на другое. И вызов `f(5,2)` — как компилятору узнать, что на что делить? :) С вашим выводом — это уже второй вопрос... но похоже на неинициализированную переменную. Кроме того, откуда я знаю, **что** вы считаете? Вы же задание так и не дали. Создавайте новый вопрос, но *правильно*, если самому лень думать...

Comment: Я не могу создать новый вопрос(

Comment: Сама формулировка задания наверно не так важна.  В общем с помощью двумерного массива задаётся матрица с числами от 0 до 9, находится сумма элементов каждой строки и сравниваются, находится максимальная сумма и минимальная.